# How can I change Validation messages based on the label

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a 'VehiclePrice' field in my Model that I am using different labels on. I have 3 different 'divs', only one of which will display based on a dropdown selection of 'Car', 'Truck', or 'SUV'. The labels are "Sedan Price", "Truck Price", and "SUV Price". I'm new to MVC and as a database guy, I don't like the idea of creating 3 different fields to hold the same thing - "Price". I need the Validation message to refer to the specific label when it spits out a "Required" or a "Range" message, i.e., "**Car** Price is required", "**Truck** Price must be between 10000 and 900000", etc, instead of just "Price is required". Why? Because there are other "Price" labels in the same 'div'. 
My instructions were that I needed to use the @Html validation stuff, which seems rather difficult to modify.
Is there a simple way to override the message or at least to prepend or append "Car", "Truck", or "SUV" to it? Or maybe a way to override some of the 'data-val-*' attributes.

Comment: Validation messages are static and parsed when the view is rendered. Some options would be to (a) handle the `.change` event of the `VehiclePrice` textbox, test i valid using `.Valid()` and if not, update the associated message, or (b) handle the `change` event of the dropdown and rewrite the `$.validator.messages`

Comment: I should have mentioned that this View also uses jquery.validate.unobtrusive and a bunch of "kendo" stuff -- none of which I know anything about. But they seem to override anything I attempt to do in jquery.  And for whoever "minus 1-ed" me, it's not very useful people who are new to ASP.NET MVC for you to do that without an explanation.

Comment: Then show what you have already tried!

Comment: I've been researching this for the last 6 hours and I've tried many things that didn't work. All of them were simple and here is one example that looks like it should have worked: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyNumberField, new { data_val_number="Car Price is Required!" }). But it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation messages are parsed by `jquery-validate` when the view is first rendered. You could change the relevant `data-val-*` attributes for the `VehiclePrice` property based on the selected vehicle type, and then reparse the validator.  Assuming the html for the select is

```
<select id="vehicletype">
  <option value="Car">Car</option>
  <option value="Truck">Truck</option>
</select>
```

Then the script

```
$('#vehicletype').change(function() {
  // Update error message
  var message= 'The ' + $(this).val() + ' price is required';
  $('#VehiclePrice').attr('data-val-required', message);
  // Reparse validator
  $('form').data('validator', null);
  $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));
});
```

Note you would also need to check the vehicle type on post back and adjust the ModelState error message to suit if you return the view

Comment: Side note: You might want to add `$('#vehicletype').trigger('change');` in `document.ready()` so the error message is updated when the page is first rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a Vehicle Type property to your view model and use a bool variable in your view to set the text boxes to enabled or not enabled via JQuery in the document.ready event. If the disabled variable is false then the validation for the text box will be ignored. Use the code below for each vehicle type div.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.VehiclePrice, new { @type = "range", min = 10000, max = 15000 }, disabled)  
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(r => r.VehiclePrice,"Price must be between 10000 and 15,000")
```

Comment: Your misunderstanding OP's requirements! OP already has that, but wants the message to change (_"The car price ..."_ or _"The truck price..."_) based on selection of an option

Comment: Well, that takes care of the "range" thing, but then how do I handle "Required"?

Comment: @McAuley, How does that take care of the _range thing_. It give the same message if you have selected a car or a truck - you indicated you want different messages

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, you're right.  I'm out of my depth here. I'm in the unenviable position of being thrown into a situation with no background or training in the MVC4 world and I'm given a deadline. It is tempting to punt and just show generic messages. This would be easy in traditional HTML and jquery.

Comment: I would also suggest sticking with the built in MVC features - while it would be possible, its complex and you then need to replicate the conditional checks on the server and generate a custom message if you return the view. A better way might be to use a view model with 3 `Price` properties, decorated with a [foolproof ](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]` attribute

Comment: I assume you mean Price properties such as CarPrice, TruckPrice, and SUVPrice in a View Model, and they'd have the "[NotMapped]" attribute?

Comment: Yes, but in a view model. A `[NotMapped]` would not be necessary since you don't save the view model, you map its properties to the data model and save that. The 3 properties would each have a `[Display]` attribute for the label, and the `[Required]` and `[Range]` attributes with specific messages, then hide of show the respective elements based on the selected option